# Simplifying an expression by multiplication of terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I have an expression $e^{x-a}(e^{bx}+c)$. I just want it multiplied throughout to get $e^{(b+1)x-a}+ce^{x-a}$. To achieve this I have tried `Expand`, `Simplify`, `Collect` (using pattern `Exp[q_*x]`). The best output I could get is

```
Expand[Exp[x-a]*(Exp[b*x]+c)]
(* Exp[-a+x+b*x]+c*Exp[-a+x] *)
```

I have tried `Evaluate` after this step to obtain proper exponent, but to no avail. How do I make it come with $e^{(b+1)x-a}$ in the first term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a rule:

```
Expand[Exp[x - a]*(Exp[b*x] + c)] /. Exp[a_] :> Exp[Collect[a, x]]
```

[image]

See also:

- [Variable order in output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131857/variable-order-in-output)
- [How to keep `Collect[]` result in order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15744/how-to-keep-collect-result-in-order)

Answer (score 2):

`MapAt` with specified position:

```
tmp = Exp[x - a] (Exp[b x] + c) // Expand;
pos = Position[tmp, p_Plus /; ! FreeQ[p, x]];
MapAt[Collect[#, x] &, tmp, pos]
```

> `c E^(-a + x) + E^(-a + (1 + b) x)`

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. It is nice to be aware of different ways of approaching a problem.